# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable (subbing into formula)

Tags: python

When finding travtimes error is in 3rd last line, which occurs as a result of trying to substitute flows into the lambda formula in adj, code as follows:

```
import numpy as np

edges = np.array([[0, 1, lambda N: N/100],
                  [0, 2, lambda N: 45],
                  [1, 3, lambda N: 45],
                  [2, 3, lambda N: N/100]])

nodes = np.unique(edges[:,0:2])

num_nodes = len(nodes)
adj = np.full((num_nodes, num_nodes), np.inf, dtype=object)

nodelen = len(edges)
for x in range(nodelen):
    edge = edges[x,:]  # 0, 1, lambda ... need to loop through edges
    first, second, func = edge
    adj[first, second] = func

flows = np.zeros_like(adj)
print(adj)
print(flows)
adjlen = len(adj)
y=0
travtimes = adj
travtimes.astype(dtype=object)
flows.astype(dtype=int)
while y < adjlen:
    for x in range(adjlen):
        travtimes[x,y] = travtimes[x,y](flows[x,y])
    y = y+1

print(travtimes)
```

Comment: All of the values in `adj` and then `travtimes` are `inf`. You can't call an `inf` value as a function, which is what that line is doing. You probably would be best served by taking a step back, thinking more about what you're doing there, and possibly writing out in plain language what you would like to do; only then translating to code.

Comment: I've added an embedded if loop inside to skip the inf values and only use the function but am still receiving the same error, any ideas?

Comment: Ah, now I see the lambdas in there. Ok, you should probably edit the question to include what you tried, because it sounds like now there's a problem with that approach.